# How to check for certain characters at the end of a user input? Python

Tags: python, string, user-input

My program asks the user to enter the name of a file that they want opened.

If they put `.txt` at the end, the file will be opened.

How can I make my program prevent non-`.txt` extensions, so that my program will add it on anyway so that the correct program gets entered.

Comment: Could you edit in the code, please?

Answer (score 6):

There is already the string method `.endswith`

```
>>> 'test.txt'.endswith('.txt')
True
>>> 'test.png'.endswith('.txt')
False
```

If it does not already end with the correct extension, you'll have to think of what inputs you could possible get and add it for them. This could be either the wrong kind of extension or no extension. This could get tricky to catch all the edge cases.